# Ran the same code on Jupyter notebook and got a memory error

Tags: python, jupyter

I ran SVM-related code in Jupyter notebook a month ago. At that time, the results were excellent. There are a few things I've checked recently that have run the code as it is, but with memory errors. I do not know the reason.

I tried rebooting the computer and reinstalling conda.

Code:

```
x = dataset['x']
y = dataset['y']
ss0_train = ss0['train']
ss0_test = ss0['test']

training_image_array, training_label_array = x[ss0_train], y[ss0_train]
test_image_array, test_label_array = x[ss0_test], y[ss0_test]

ori = training_image_array
bat = np.zeros((144338,133))
cat = np.hstack([ori,bat])
training_image_array = cat

ori2 = test_image_array
bat2 = np.zeros((16037,133))
cat2 = np.hstack([ori2,bat2])
test_image_array = cat2

train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y = training_image_array, training_label_array, test_image_array, test_label_array


from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV

cclf = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=LinearSVC(penalty='l2', dual=False), cv=5)
cclf.fit(train_X,train_y_arg)
```

Error:

```
 MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-10-85ee7435c48f> in <module>()
  3 
  4 cclf = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=LinearSVC(penalty='l2', dual=False), cv=5)
  ----> 5 cclf.fit(train_X,train_y_arg)

  D:\Users\GIL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\calibration.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
  179              
                        sample_weight=base_estimator_sample_weight[train])
  180                 else:
--> 181                     this_estimator.fit(X[train], y[train])
  182 
  183                 calibrated_classifier = _CalibratedClassifier(

  MemoryError:
```

Comment: Is the error message really just `MemoryError:`? Also, could you try uploading the notebook to [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) to see if you can reproduce the error there? If you can reproduce it, please add a link to the colab notebook here.

Comment: @Taxel Yes, it is. It is just a memory error. As a further finding, I used only 20GB to import the input data. However, when an error occurs, it seems that the input data occupies all the memory. For reference, my computer currently has 64GB of memory. Unfortunately, there is no link that I can't use google colab.